# StaticProperties in Resource Dictionary

Tags: xaml, mvvm, binding, static

My XAML has been working fine, referencing a Static Property of a static class

```
<TextBox IsReadOnly="{x:Static loc:StateMachine.IsReadOnly}" />
```

I now want to refactor the above, so I can use a ResourceDictionary

So, my resource dictionary is

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:stat="clr-namespace:MyProjectHelper"
                    >

    <stat:StateMachine x:Key="StaticResources" />

</ResourceDictionary>
```

On my XAML, I removed the namespace reference called loc (which I was using) and I add a reference to the resource dictionary (which works since my views show and converters do their job) but when I add the following code

```
 <TextBox IsReadOnly="{StaticResource StaticResources.IsReadOnly}" />
```

I get a runtime exception

> 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '50' and line position '97'.

My research shows this is something wrong wit the XML - it could be a typo (checked) or an unexpected value but I can't see what I need to do to fix this despite looking over SO and Google

I also tried

```
 <TextBox IsReadOnly="{Binding Source={StaticResource StaticResources}, Path=IsReadOnly}" />
```

but the exception is

> 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'SeoHelper.StateMachine' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '9' and line position '6'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{StaticResource }` binding needs to be able to instantiate your class, and it had problem to do so because the class was static. Your last trial would've worked if only the class wasn't declared as static.

Possible workaround if you need to keep your class static is, you can register the property instead of the class to resource dictionary using `StaticExtension` :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:stat="clr-namespace:MyProjectHelper"
                    >
    <x:StaticExtension Member="stat:StateMachine.IsReadOnly" x:Key="StaticResources"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then binding to the resource can be done as usual :

```
<TextBox IsReadOnly="{StaticResource StaticResources}" />
```